# R Create One Hot Vector From List Elements

Tags: r, plyr

I am trying to process some character strings for an input file.  First I convert the strings from a vector to a list, then I reduce to only unique values.

Next I would like to convert the words in each list element into a string with a separator of ':1 '.

I can get the function to work on a single list element but when I try to use `ldply` from `plyr` to do it for the whole list, I only get the last word in each list element.

Here's the code:

```
library(plyr)

df1 <- data.frame(id = seq(1,5,1), string1 = NA)
head(df1)
df1$string1[1] <- "This string is a string."
df1$string1[2] <- "This string is a slightly longer string."
df1$string1[3] <- "This string is an even longer string."
df1$string1[4] <- "This string is a slightly shorter string."
df1$string1[5] <- "This string is the longest string of all the other strings."

df1$string1 <- tolower(as.character(df1$string1))
df1$string1 <- gsub('[[:punct:]]',' ',df1$string1)
df1$string1 <- gsub('[[:digit:]]',' ',df1$string1)
df1$string1 <- gsub("\\s+"," ",df1$string1)

fdList1 <- strsplit(df1$string1, " ", df1$string1)
fdList2 <- lapply(fdList1, unique)

toString1 <- function(x){
string2 <- c()
#print(length(x[1][1]))
#print(x)
#print(class(x))
for(i in length(x)){
string2 <- paste0(string2, x[[i]], ":1 ", collapse="")
}
string2
}

df2 <- ldply(fdList2, toString1)
df2 

v1 <- toString1(fdList2[2])
v1
```

`df2` is wrong, I would like a vector similar to `v1` for each list element.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try this: `ldply(seq(length(fdList2)), function(x) toString1(fdList2[x]))`. Your function seems to be passing `[[.]]` instead of `[.]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To explain why this is happening:

Your function `toString1` is the issue:

```
toString1 <- function(x) {
    string2 <- c()
    for(i in length(x)) { 
        string2 <- paste0(string2, x[[i]], ":1 ", collapse="")
    }
    string2
}
```

In the case of `toString1(fdList2[1])`, you're passing a list. So, there is no use for the `for-loop`. It would work if your function is:

```
toString1 <- function(x) {
    string2 <- paste0(x[[1]], ":1 ", collapse="")
}
o <- toString1(fdList2[2])

# [1] "this:1 string:1 is:1 a:1 slightly:1 longer:1 "
```

But when you do `ldply`, what you're passing is not the list (`fdList2[2]`), but a vector (`fdList2[[2]]`). So, in this case, your function should be:

```
toString1 <- function(x) {
    string2 <- c()
    for(i in 1:length(x)) { 
        string2 <- paste0(string2, x[i], ":1 ", collapse="")
    }
    string2
}
ldply(fdList2, toString1)

#                                                                   V1
# 1                                          this:1 string:1 is:1 a:1 
# 2                      this:1 string:1 is:1 a:1 slightly:1 longer:1 
# 3                         this:1 string:1 is:1 an:1 even:1 longer:1 
# 4                     this:1 string:1 is:1 a:1 slightly:1 shorter:1 
# 5 this:1 string:1 is:1 the:1 longest:1 of:1 all:1 other:1 strings:1
```

Note the change of `length(x)` in the for-loop to `1:length(x)` as it has to cycle through ALL elements and `x[[i]]` to `x[i]` because its a vector.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use `sapply` on "fdList2"?

```
> sapply(fdList2, paste0, ":1 ", collapse = "")
[1] "this:1 string:1 is:1 a:1 "                                         
[2] "this:1 string:1 is:1 a:1 slightly:1 longer:1 "                     
[3] "this:1 string:1 is:1 an:1 even:1 longer:1 "                        
[4] "this:1 string:1 is:1 a:1 slightly:1 shorter:1 "                    
[5] "this:1 string:1 is:1 the:1 longest:1 of:1 all:1 other:1 strings:1 "
> ## If you need a single column data.frame
> data.frame(V1 = sapply(fdList2, paste0, ":1 ", collapse = ""))
                                                                  V1
1                                          this:1 string:1 is:1 a:1 
2                      this:1 string:1 is:1 a:1 slightly:1 longer:1 
3                         this:1 string:1 is:1 an:1 even:1 longer:1 
4                     this:1 string:1 is:1 a:1 slightly:1 shorter:1 
5 this:1 string:1 is:1 the:1 longest:1 of:1 all:1 other:1 strings:1
```

For that matter, if this is really your target, you can simplify your intermediate steps even further. Skip the creation of "fdList1" and "fdList2" and just use:

```
sapply(strsplit(df1$string1, " "), 
       function(x) paste0(unique(x), ":1 ", collapse = ""))
```

Comment: I probably should have done that in the first place. Thank you.